# SSL/TLS error with website

Tags: ssl, websense

I have a website using tls1.2,1.1 and 1.0(ssllabs) . I am using websense proxy to access it. Have enabled tls1.1 and tls1.2 on the WCG. I am still getting Peer disconnected error. The website worked once and is giving the error randomly. I have websense 8 and the URL in question is **https://rem2.piiapps.com/site/login**. It works fine with websense 7. I dont have a ssl bypass option due to security restrictions. Sometimes the browser indicates that the certificate is broken and sometimes it is healthy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming or anything related to this. And since this problem is happening sporadically, did not exist with Websense 7 but exists with Websense 8 it looks more like a question you should ask the support of Websense.

Comment: yes, it is not related to programming. But its not sporadic. The site never worked as it should except for one instance. The knowledge article by websense support say this issue was with 8.0 version of websense, ours is 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I did some analysis and found that this URL was using a real time communication protocol which is not supported by deafult in websense. It has to be tunneled in the incident list.